# Couldnot create the Java virtual machine.Fatal exception occurred

Tags: java, jvm

I have been installing JDK 1.8 U 45 on a win 7 system and I am getting the following error:

> Could not create the Java virtual machine.Fatal exception occurred,

but I could install JDK.
since the path is not automatically set, I had to set the path environment variable pointing to the bin and other env.variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`.
When I execute `java -version`,It is picking up `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and then version is printed. Now my problem is I couldn't find JAVA in the control panel.
Is the Java virtual machine correctly installed? If so Why would I not see it in the control panel.
Please help.

Comment: Which command gives you the error message `Could not create the Java virtual machine.Fatal exception occurred`?

Comment: Iam getting the error as part of JDK installation..

Answer (score 0):

Solved.After installing java for the system.